# How to Safely Relocate a Robins nest?

Tags: animals, birds

Right outside of my backdoor to my house, a [robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_robin) has decided to build a nest on top of my homes electrical meter:

[image: nest]

<s>So far, I do not see any eggs in the nest</s> There is now [one egg present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrvo2.jpg).  How can I relocate it (or should I)? My main concern is the fact that my backdoor is right here. I don't want to open it one day to find a robin starring at me.

Comment: Congratulations on your new arrival.

Comment: @Darren not to be the bearer of bad news - but a few weeks ago the eggs disappeared from the nest... I think a predator unfortunately got to them :(  - I left the question in case others come across a similar situation.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was only posted today as it was at the top of the list. I didn’t look at the dates. Sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no eggs just take it down and discard. Some birds ( eg. Carolina wrens) build a couple nests and then pick the best one for eggs ( don't know about robins). Also , I have seen a Carolina wren build the bulk of a nest in a few hours.

Comment: Too late now - [an egg has appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrvo2.jpg)!  Mama was also sitting in the nest earlier.  I'll just have to try to be mindful of them now and wait it out.

Comment: They will be gone in less than 2 months. And they picked the location as satisfactory.